# Meaning of idempotency in the context of HTTP PUT?

Tags: http, rest, put, http-verbs, idempotent

In [this presentation on REST](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=mZ8_QgJ5mbs#t=1020) (timestamp 17:00-18:45), the speaker says that an HTTP `PUT` must include all the properties for a resource, and not be used for partial updates. This is required in HTTP because otherwise it is not idempotent.

His definition of idempotency is (and this sounds reasonable):

> idempotent is any operation that can be performed once or multiple
>   times and result in the same server state

However, he then goes on to give an example where (paraphrased):

> Request A: I use a `PUT` to update only the name property of a resource.
>
> Request B: I use a `PUT` to update only the description.
>
> In between A and B another client could specify the name, then after request B, the
>   resource has the other client's name, and my description. Because the
>   server state isn't the same after request A and B, that's not an
>   idempotent operation.

I'm not sure about this interpretation: for me, idempotency only tells you something about what happens when you run the *same* operation multiple times in a row. In the above example, request A and B are two different operations, so there is no reason to think that running A then B should be have any special guarantees; in particular, there is no reason to think they should together constitute an atomic operation.

Running request A multiple times would have the same effect as running it once (likewise for B), so I would have thought it idempotent (even if this was an incorrect use of `PUT` for other reasons).

Is my understanding incorrect?

(Note: this is intended to be a question about the meaning of idempotency, not the appropriate use of `PUT`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right; a partial update can be idempotent.

That doesn't change the fact that PUT is not for partial updates; if you need a partial update you ought to use PATCH.